# NSOuputStream sends Old Value - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, sockets, nsoutputstream

I have created code used for sockets for send/receive value. I did it all. first time it works well. I face the problem is Whenever i send the new value at second time, the old value is passed. like, first time i send 0 value to socket, the log file on socket side is receive as "0" in log file and i received data from sever, its working well. but when i send another value like "2" to socket, but the server socket receiving previous value as "0" in log file. i cant send new value.

My code is

Appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property (strong) NSOutputStream *outputStream;

- (void) applicationDdifinishLaunching....{
[self initNetworkCommunication:@"192.168.1.38"];
}
```

Appdelegate.m

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication:(NSString *) getIp {
NSLog(@"GETIP = %@",getIp);
CFStringRef aCFString = (__bridge CFStringRef)getIp;

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, aCFString, 1500, &readStream, &writeStream);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

NSInputStream *inStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *) readStream;
NSOutputStream *outStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *) writeStream;

[inStream setDelegate:self];
[outStream setDelegate:self];
[inStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inStream open];
[outStream open];

self.inputStream = inStream;
self.outputStream = outStream;
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(StartDatatoServer:) withObject:@"0"];
}



- (void) StartDatatoServer:(id) get
{
NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",get];
//NSData *datafixed = [[command stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *data = (NSMutableData *)[[command stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned long length = [data length];

uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *) [data bytes];
uint8_t buffer[length];
(void)memcpy(buffer, readBytes, length);
length = [outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:length];
if (-1 == length) {
        NSLog(@"Error writing to stream %@: %@", outputStream, [outputStream streamError]);
} else {
        NSLog(@"Wrote %ld bytes to stream %@.", (long)length, outputStream);
}
[self writeLogFile:command TypeName:@"ServerStart"];
}




- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent { 
switch (streamEvent) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
    {
        if ([theStream isKindOfClass:[inputStream class]]) {
            NSLog(@"Input stream opened");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"output stream opened");
        }
        break;
    }
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        NSLog(@"NSEvethaspcape");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        // Listening Server Acknowledgement
        NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
        if (theStream == inputStream) {
        }
        break;
    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
         NSLog(@"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred");
        // When disconnect or Error occured between socket & server
        break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        // Occur when Server is Closed
        NSLog(@"NSStreamEventEndEncountered");
        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        theStream = nil;
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event");
}
}
```

In Windowcontroller.h

anObject = @"2";

```
-(void) LoginConnectionProcess:(id)anObject
{

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.inputStream.delegate = self;
appDelegate.outputStream.delegate = self;

NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",anObject];
NSMutableData *data = (NSMutableData *)[[command stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned long length =
[data length];
NSLog(@"anOjbe= %@",command);
uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *) [data bytes];
uint8_t buffer[length];
(void)memcpy(buffer, readBytes, length);
length = [appDelegate.outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:length];
if (-1 == length) {
    NSLog(@"Errors writing to stream %@: %@", appDelegate.outputStream, [appDelegate.outputStream streamError]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Wrotes %ld bytes to stream %@.", (long)length, appDelegate.outputStream);
}
}


- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
switch (streamEvent) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"ConnectionOpened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
        if (theStream == appDelegate.inputStream) {

        }
        break;
    }
    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        theStream = nil;
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown Events");
}
}
```

and whenever i called second time, the stream "NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable" function only fired. but the "NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable" function is never called. What i missing/issue in here.
Waiting your reply.
Any help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The code looks pretty rotten.  Why are you resetting the stream delegates?  Why doesn't the second code fragment use `StartDatatoServer:`?  Why copy the `NSData` object to a buffer when you can just as easily access the bytes directly within the `NSData` object?

Comment: @trojanfoe then how can i access NSOuputstream to send data, and need to send data immediately when socket is opened

Comment: Any code that wants to send data can call `StartDataToServer:` and that will interact with the streams.

Comment: @trojanfoe ok. I'm sending data  as "0" to server, when connection opened I replced that code to "NSStreamEventOpenCompleted" function. Still same working. i called that first time only. I have one doubt. can you clarify me, is that function often call again?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm using this same code again, bt same output. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844350/ios-outputstream-does-not-stay-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just called the following code, it would be flushed

```
NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r",username.StringValue];
NSData *data = [command dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```